# Code is not printing results

Tags: java, input, output

I'm getting the prompt to enter an integer but nothing after that. Can someone tell me why my results are not printing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChapterThreeQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a three-digit integer: ");
        double answer = input.nextDouble();


        double x = input.nextDouble();
        double y = input.nextDouble();
        double z = input.nextDouble();


        if (x == z && y == y && z == x)
            System.out.println(answer + " is a palindrome! ");
        else
            System.out.println(answer + " is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's waiting for input.

Comment: I wonder when you expect `y == y` to be false.

Comment: Why are you reading integers and assigning to doubles?

Comment: Also, `x == z && z == x` is equivalent to `x == z` because the `==` operation is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). And as `y == y` is always `true`, the whole condition can be reduced to `if (x == z) ...`.

Comment: @shmosel if you enter `NaN`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Nice one.

Comment: It asks for an input. I'm have a problem with comparing the input. I'm assuming I need to store the input in order to do a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
double answer = input.nextDouble();
double x = input.nextDouble();
double y = input.nextDouble();
double z = input.nextDouble();
```

Your code is waiting for 4 different inputs.  If you input all 4, it will run - but something is clearly wrong with your logic.

Comment: How would I write the logic to do a comparison on each integer?

Comment: First of all, you need to actually use integers, and not doubles.  Once you do that, you can use the % and / operators to get the digits.  Are you familiar with integer division in Java, and how the modulus operator works?

Comment: I'm new to this but I know " / " divides and "%" gives a remainder.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you are a) working with doubles and b) trying to read too many numbers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChapterThreeQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a three-digit integer: ");

         // Read an int
        int answer = 0;
        try {
            answer = input.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            // Handle error
        }

        // Make sure it's 3 digits
        if (answer < 100 || answer >= 1000) {
           // Do something with bad input
        }
        else {
            // Just need to check if first and third digits are equal.
            // Get those values using integer math
            int digit1 = answer / 100;
            int digit3 = answer % 10;
            if (digit1 == digit3) {
                System.out.println(answer + " is a palindrome! ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(answer + " is not a palindrome");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand the math part. 181 (3 digit = 1) what divisor  is being used to have a remainder of 10?

Comment: `181 % 10 = 1` because "181 / 10 = 18 with a remainder of 1". That's how modulo works - it returns the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Palindrome
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String original, reverse = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter a string : ");
      original = in.nextLine();

      int length = original.length();

      for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

      if (original.equals(reverse))
         System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
      else
         System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
    }
}

/*
OUTPUT:
Enter a string : MADAM
Entered string is a palindrome.

Enter a string : 15351
Entered string is a palindrome.
*/
```

You are using wrong logic here.If you want to check for palindrome, you should not use double.Hope this code helps!